# how can i add multiple entries having the same input form name (html,php)

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="confirm.php" method="post" name="">
Hobby : <input type="text" name="f_hobby" value="" placeholder="Enter your Hobby"/>
<br />
Hobby : <input type="text" name="f_hobby" value="" placeholder="Enter another Hobby"/>
<br />
<button type="submit" class="">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It should save on my database table as two consecutive rows.

---

What if I have a radio button ?

```
Hobby : <input type="text" name="f_hobby[]" value="" placeholder="Enter your Hobby"/>
Status : <input name="f_status[]" type="radio" value="1" /> ON <input name="f_status[]" type="radio" value="0" /> OFF  
<br>
Hobby : <input type="text" name="f_hobby[]" value="" placeholder="Enter your Hobby"/>
Status : <input name="f_status[]" type="radio" value="1" /> ON <input name="f_status[]" type="radio" value="0" /> OFF  
<br>
Hobby : <input type="text" name="f_hobby[]" value="" placeholder="Enter your Hobby"/>
    Status : <input name="f_status[]" type="radio" value="1" /> ON <input name="f_status[]" type="radio" value="0" /> OFF  
<br>
```

I added a form Radio Button for example Status . ..
Does not work with radio buttons...

Answer (score 0):

Add `[]` to the input names:

```
<form action="confirm.php" method="post" name="">
Hobby : <input type="text" name="f_hobby[]" value="" placeholder="Enter your Hobby"/>
<br />
Hobby : <input type="text" name="f_hobby[]" value="" placeholder="Enter another Hobby"/>
<br />
<button type="submit" class="">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then in your `confirm.php` variable `$_POST['f_hobby']` will contain an array of the input data:

```
print_r( $_POST["f_hobby"] ); // Array ( [0] => sleeping [1] => eating )
```